# Mysql order by data from other table

Tags: mysql

I have table '**orderby**'

```
+-----------------+
| id | data       |
+-----------------+
| 1  | 4,2,5,6    |
+-----------------+
```

and second table **data**

```
+-----------+
| id | ...  |
+-----------+
| 2  | ...  |
+-----------+
| 4  | ...  |
+-----------+
| 5  | ...  |
+-----------+
| 6  | ...  |
+-----------+
```

i want to sort **data** table by **orderby** tables data column.

like this:

```
+-----------+
| id | ...  |
+-----------+
| 4  | ...  |
+-----------+
| 2  | ...  |
+-----------+
| 5  | ...  |
+-----------+
| 6  | ...  |
+-----------+
```

i tried this query: `select * from data order by field(id,(select group_concat(data) from orderby))`

but not works.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution would be to add a column `orderby INT UNSIGNED` to your `data` table, and use numbers to get the correct order.

If you need the ordering to be user dependant, you'll have to use a separate table with user id, data id (from your `data` table) and orderby value.

A single `orderby` value as you are using in your code, will not work. (It might be possible, but I think it would be hard to implement and it would not perform well.)